# Is there an alternative SSO to CAS which supports gateway mode?

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

CAS supports a gateway mode (http://www.jasig.org/cas/client-integration/gateway), which doesn't force the user to sign in when accessing a non-secured resource, but if the user is already authenticated, they'll be signed in.

Lets say there's server A and B which have secured and non-secured pages. The user accesses a secured page on A and is forced to sing in with SSO. Then accesses non-secured page on B and although there is no need to authenticate, it should get the ticket because they're signed on.

Does any other SSOs support this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Shibboleth has the same feature : http://shibboleth.1660669.n2.nabble.com/how-can-I-ask-for-but-not-require-a-lazy-session-td5084205.html...

Comment: Looks like it. I think JOSSO's "login_optional" is another option.